# How to delete sub-folder database in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I create a new database, a lot of sub-folders and some tables are created, I want to ask if they are needed or not?

I have tried to find ways to delete some unnecessary things but did not find a way?

[image]

Comment: Those four are all empty folders. They are part of the SSMS UI and always shown - there is nothing in the database corresponding to those folders

Comment: Hi @MartinSmith: yes! they are empty folders!. Can I create an empty database without empty folders? or how do i delete these folders?

Comment: you don't. They don't exist in the database. This is just part of the SSMS UI. If you had graph tables you would get to them by expanding the Graphs table folder and so on

Comment: they are the default directory created except the system table, but I'm not sure if it is needed.

Comment: although they do not exist but I'm pretty hard to see and manage the other tables, they're quite entangled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot delete them:

> [Hide System Objects in Object Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/object/hide-system-objects-in-object-explorer?view=sql-server-ver15)
>
> Options -> Environment/Startup -> Hide system objects in Object Explorer -> OK -> Restart SSMS

Comment: Hi, it helped me a lot, if I couldn't delete them maybe I would have to adapt to it.. Thanks!